# python: single-line cartesian product for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Did you know you can do this?

```
>>> [(x,y) for x in xrange(2) for y in xrange(5)]
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

It's neat. Is there a for loop version or can one only do this for list comprehensions?

EDIT: I think my question was misunderstood. I want to know if there is special syntax for this:

```
for x in xrange(2) <AND> y in xrange(5):
    print "do stuff here"
    print "which doesn't fit into a list comprehension"
    print "like printing x and y cause print is a statement", x, y
```

I could do this, but it seems a bit repetitive:

```
for x,y in ((x,y) for x in xrange(2) for y in xrange(5)):
    print x, y
```

Comment: No, you can't. That is only for list-comprehensions.

Comment: +1 rubik is correct, this isn't supported syntax.

Comment: @samplebias: ah if only one could accept a comment as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well there's no syntax for what you want, but there is [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for x, y in itertools.product([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]): print x, y
... 
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
[ ... and so on ... ]
```

Answer (score 5):

That is an equivalent, more compact version of:

```
def values():
    for x in xrange(2):
        for y in xrange(5):
            yield (x, y)
list(values())
```

**Update**: To compare bytecode of both, do this:

```
import dis
print dis.dis(values)   # above function

gen = ((x,y) for x in xrange(2) for y in xrange(5))
print dis.dis(gen.gi_code)
```

Comment: is that an exact equivalent? (does python actually make a generator for every list comprehension?). otherwise, of course the output would be the same

Comment: Yep, the bytecode is pretty close although I think the generator is a bit more efficient.

Comment: Well, of course it doesn't define a full throwaway generator for every list comprehension. It also won't unroll it into a python-level loop. But such implementation details don't matter, and neither does the fact that this example defines a generator. It's the nesting of loops that matters. (Edit: To nitpick, OP is using a list comprehension, which is implemented differently with special bytecodes!)

Comment: @delnan: ah depends on the level of the question. i agree initially it looked like i didnt know what nesting was, but it is pretty obvious to me - so taking the equivalence of the output as a given i was seeing if there was something more to your answer. thats a neat trick with looking at the byte-code!