# Python nested looping Idiom

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, foreach, idioms

I often find myself doing this:

```
for x in range(x_size):
    for y in range(y_size):
        for z in range(z_size):
            pass # do something here
```

Is there a more concise way to do this in Python? I am thinking of something along the lines of

```
for x, z, y in ... ? :
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> for x,y,z in itertools.product(range(2), range(2), range(3)):
...     print x,y,z
... 
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up going a different route as I can't use itertools, but, after reviewing the documentation for itertools, that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: It's worth noting that one of  the great things about itertools.product is that it isn't creating the intermediate lists, which would involve lots of appends and behind the scenes array resizing and memory operations. Thus this version is not only elegant, but also faster and much easier on the garbage collector! If your nested loop is taking up a lot of your runtime when profiled this approach is worth trying.

Answer (score 8):

If you've got `numpy` as a dependency already, [`numpy.ndindex`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndindex.html#numpy.ndindex) will do the trick ...

```
>>> for x,y,z in np.ndindex(2,2,2):
...     print x,y,z
... 
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Comment: Hmm ... Apparently this does the same thing as `itertools.product`.  Should have seen that one coming... :-)

Comment: I like this solution! It is really concise, although it would be more a `numpy` idiom than a python idiom.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- I come from the perspective that `python` without `numpy` is just a shiny toy ... But I know that's not everybody's perspective :-).

Answer (score 7):

Use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for x, y, z in itertools.product(range(x_size), range(y_size), range(z_size)):
    pass # do something here
```

From the docs:

> Cartesian product of input iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression.
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is inside the loop.  If dealing with lists, you may be able to use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

For the more general case, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759770/python-single-line-cartesian-product-for-loop) on itertools.